# qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault)

Tags: embedded-linux, qemu, scratchbox

Inside scratch box i am performing git clone, getting following error:

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
```

Error:

```
/pi$ sb2 -t rfs-raspbian -eR git clone git://github.com/danwinship/glib.git
Cloning into 'glib'...
remote: Counting objects: 72484, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11555/11555), done.
remote: Total 72484 (delta 61357), reused 71916 (delta 60808)
Receiving objects: 100% (72484/72484), 28.86 MiB | 59 KiB/s, done.
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
error: index-pack died of signal 11
fatal: index-pack failed
```

QEmu version installed :

```
qemu-arm -version  
qemu-arm version 1.3.90, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard

qemu-system-arm -version
QEMU emulator version 1.3.90, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Any suggestion how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 4):

I've obtained the same error while running git in qemu-static-aarch64 chroot. I've resolved this problem by compiling git without **threads** use.