# qemu uncaught target signal 11 when running dpkg --configure libc-bin

Tags: docker, segmentation-fault, debian, cross-compiling, qemu

When running a docker container (`arm64v8`/`aarch64`) on my host machine (`amd64`) and trying to install/configure libc-bin on a debian container, it gives me the following error:

```
[ cut for size, full log at https://pastebin.com/7ZtvqZsD ]
#6 18.65 Setting up libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u3) ...
#6 18.92 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#6 19.03 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
#6 19.06 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#6 19.15 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
#6 19.15 dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
#6 19.15  installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
#6 19.20 Errors were encountered while processing:
#6 19.20  libc-bin
#6 19.31 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -y reinstall libc-bin]: exit code: 100
```

### Minimal reproducible example

```
FROM arm64v8/debian
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y reinstall libc-bin
```

### Versions

```
$ qemu-system-aarch64 --version # installed via pacman -S qemu-full
QEMU emulator version 7.0.0
Copyright (c) 2003-2022 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developer

$ qemu-system-arm --version # installed via pacman -S qemu-full
QEMU emulator version 7.0.0
Copyright (c) 2003-2022 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developer

$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c70180f

## Binfmt extensions installed with
docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all &

$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 5.18.7-zen1-1-zen #1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat, 25 Jun 2022 20:22:03 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

## OS
Arch linux
```

### Prior reading

(a.k.a. please don't mark my question as duplicates of these, it is distinct from them)

[qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped in docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862313/qemu-uncaught-target-signal-11-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-docker-con)
None of these answers work for me, I'm running the latest qemu in the arch linux repos, `arm64v8/debian` is not a deprecated container image as far as I can tell, and I'm not using docker-for-mac. Plus, this question regards the opposite direction (`amd64` containers on `arm64`).

[qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086238/qemu-uncaught-target-signal-11-segmentation-fault)
Issue doesn't stem from git, so this question's answer isn't helpful.

[qemu-arm qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54735030/qemu-arm-qemu-uncaught-target-signal-11-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)
Not helpful either, I've tried using qemu-user-static v7.0.0 (both compiled and -bin) which didn't fix my issue either. Not sure what the TCG interpreter is, so that could possibly be the issue, but I'm not familiar enough with qemu to know how to "disable the TCG interpreter".

[qemu uncaught target signal 11 segmentation fault -- only on arm64 build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337798/qemu-uncaught-target-signal-11-segmentation-fault-only-on-arm64-build)
My kernel is 5.18.7-zen1-1-zen which is newer than the 5.10.0-8 that the answer suggests, and is the latest available on arch linux repos at time of writing.

[qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped, when trying to return a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986709/qemu-uncaught-target-signal-11-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-trying)
Answers all related to C, which I'm not using.

### Goal

My ultimate goal is to build a root filesystem using `multistrap` to eventually be put on an arm64 device, but this issue is preventing me from doing pretty much anything, as running `dpkg --configure -a` is one of the steps that has to be run from the very start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bashing my head against this wall for weeks, the solution I found was:

- Use a native docker container instead of an architecture-based one

  - e.g. `FROM debian:11` instead of `FROM arm64v8/debian:11`
- Install `qemu-user-static` inside the docker container

  - e.g. `apt install qemu-user-static`
- Copy `qemu-aarch64-static` to the rootfs

  - e.g. `cp $(which qemu-aarch64-static) /rootfs_location/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64` (note the filename change as well)
- Chroot normally

  - e.g. `chroot /rootfs_location/`

I'm not sure *exactly* why this works, but it likely stems from an incompatibility between debian and the qemu-user-static binaries that were compiled for arch linux (or whatever OSes happen to be used) but i'm not entirely sure of that.